# SQL SUM Sub Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there anyway to query something like this?

```
SELECT
    SUM(
        SELECT Tbl1.Cost FROM Tbl1 WHERE Tbl1.Type = 0 +
        SELECT Tbl2.Cost FROM Tbl2 WHERE Tbl2.Type = 0 +
        SELECT Tbl3.Cost FROM Tbl3 WHERE Tbl3.Type = 0
    ) AS EstimatedCost
FROM Tbl1 <JOIN> Tbl2 <JOIN> Tbl3
GROUP BY Tbl1.id,Tbl2.id,Tbl3.id,Tbl1.num,Tbl2.num,Tbl3.num
```

**EDIT**

current sql query i have

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE (vJoboutsEst.ddTask_id, vMaterialsEst.ddTask_id, vLaborsEst.ddTask_id) AS ddTask_id,
    COALESCE (vJoboutsEst.dd_id, vMaterialsEst.dd_id, vLaborsEst.dd_id) AS dd_id,
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN vJoboutsEst.jo_cost IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE vJoboutsEst.jo_cost END
      + 
      CASE WHEN vMaterialsEst.item_amt IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE vMaterialsEst.item_amt END
      + 
      CASE WHEN vLaborsEst.labor_amt IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE vLaborsEst.labor_amt END
    ) AS EstimateCost
FROM 
vDryDock,
(
    SELECT vJoboutsEst.ddTask_id, vJoboutsEst.dd_id,SUM(vJoboutsEst.jo_cost) as jo_cost
    FROM vJoboutsEst WHERE vJoboutsEst.jo_type = 0 GROUP BY vJoboutsEst.ddTask_id, vJoboutsEst.dd_id
) vJoboutsEst 
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT vMaterialsEst.ddTask_id, vMaterialsEst.dd_id,SUM(vMaterialsEst.item_amt) as item_amt
    FROM vMaterialsEst WHERE vMaterialsEst.material_type = 0 GROUP BY vMaterialsEst.ddTask_id, vMaterialsEst.dd_id
) vMaterialsEst ON vJoboutsEst.ddTask_id = vMaterialsEst.ddTask_id
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT vLaborsEst.ddTask_id, vLaborsEst.dd_id,SUM(vLaborsEst.labor_amt) as labor_amt
    FROM vLaborsEst WHERE vLaborsEst.labor_type = 0 GROUP BY vLaborsEst.ddTask_id, vLaborsEst.dd_id
) vLaborsEst ON ISNULL(vJoboutsEst.ddTask_id, vMaterialsEst.ddTask_id) = vLaborsEst.ddTask_id
GROUP BY
    vJoboutsEst.ddTask_id, vMaterialsEst.ddTask_id, vLaborsEst.ddTask_id,
    vJoboutsEst.dd_id, vMaterialsEst.dd_id, vLaborsEst.dd_id
```

this is my sample data on database:

[See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiA9i.gif)

I have also attach the query output,
but the my desired output is something like this

```
ddTask_id    dd_id    EstimateCost
31           15       40
32           16       40
```

Comment: Could you provide the join condition? Am I right than you joins this tables on pair (id,num)?

Comment: **TAG** the database please. SQL Server, Oracle or some other.

Comment: Actually I have a sample code here can you check why my query summing up all the cost on my table. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your sample data (which didn't have any dd_id column!), you can do this by using a union all statement rather than full outer join. Try the below query:

```
SELECT 
    ddTask_id,
    dd_id,
    SUM(EstimatedCost) AS EstimateCost
FROM 
(
    SELECT vJoboutsEst.ddTask_id, vJoboutsEst.dd_id,SUM(vJoboutsEst.jo_cost) as EstimatedCost
    FROM vJoboutsEst WHERE vJoboutsEst.jo_type = 0 GROUP BY vJoboutsEst.ddTask_id, vJoboutsEst.dd_id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT vMaterialsEst.ddTask_id, vMaterialsEst.dd_id,SUM(vMaterialsEst.item_amt) as EstimatedCost
    FROM vMaterialsEst WHERE vMaterialsEst.material_type = 0 GROUP BY vMaterialsEst.ddTask_id, vMaterialsEst.dd_id

    UNION ALL


    SELECT vLaborsEst.ddTask_id, vLaborsEst.dd_id,SUM(vLaborsEst.labor_amt) as EstimatedCost
    FROM vLaborsEst WHERE vLaborsEst.labor_type = 0 GROUP BY vLaborsEst.ddTask_id, vLaborsEst.dd_id
)aa
GROUP BY
    ddTask_id, dd_id
```

Comment: Is the Sum(EstimatedCost) is same in my query?

Comment: Yes, you can try running it yourself!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this query :

```
 SELECT
        SUM(
            (SELECT sum(Tbl1.Cost) FROM Tbl1 WHERE Tbl1.Type = 0) +
            (SELECT sum(Tbl2.Cost) FROM Tbl2 WHERE Tbl2.Type = 0) +
            (SELECT sum(Tbl3.Cost) FROM Tbl3 WHERE Tbl3.Type = 0)
        ) AS EstimatedCost
    FROM Tbl1 <JOIN> Tbl2 <JOIN> Tbl3
    GROUP BY Tbl1.id,Tbl2.id,Tbl3.id,Tbl1.num,Tbl2.num,Tbl3.num
```